# Light going out when furnace or refrigerator kick off

Tags: electrical

I have recently added a new circuit in my basement that includes a couple of wall switches connected to can lights in the ceiling and a 4 plug outlet. One of the can lights has a habit of going out, even though the wall switch is still in the on position. When I turn the switch off and back on, the light comes back on just fine.

After some observation I have noticed 2 events that trigger the light to turn off. It happens when the condenser on a mini-fridge shuts off (not on) and also happens when the furnace kicks off (not on). The mini fridge is on the same circuit with the affected light, but the furnace is not. The breaker is not being thrown and nothing but this light seems to be affected.

It is a cheapo LED light, so not so easy to just replace a bulb. I assume I could find one online if that's what I need to do, but I was hoping for some troubleshooting suggestions first.

Any idea what could be causing this?

edit: To clarify, it doesn't happen every time the appliances kick off, but a few times a day.

Comment: Are the other lights the same cheapo LEDs?

Comment: There is only one other light and it is identical yes. It is not on as frequently so it is possible it might also be affected and I just haven't noticed.

Comment: Photos of everything you touched would help, it *might* be a flaw in your work, it's harder than you think to get all the details right when you're relatively new at it.

Comment: I'm going to test Jeff's suggestion below and will take some pics while doing so. Weird update, last night I left the second LED on to see if it was also affected, and when it is on, I can't even get the first light to go out. So maybe the appliances kicking off is causing a surge that one light can't take but two can? Or gremlins?

Answer (score 0):

Easy troubleshooting...I would say it is the LED's you have, but you can put a spare or el cheapo pull chain light kit up and test with regular incandescent bulb. If you don't have the same issue, then it is your cheapo LED's. Issue persists, then it is a wiring issue somewhere.

You can use any kind of light fixture for your testing purposes, or even convert one into an outlet for a moment and use a plug in table lamp.

Comment: Makes sense. I will give this a shot.